# Origin of the word "Tholian" in Star Trek

Tags: star-trek, terminology

I recently learned that the word "tholian" is an [Old English word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BEolian#Old_English) meaning "to suffer, endure." Is it known whether Judy Burns and Chet Richards knew this fact, and deliberately created a "Web of Suffering," or is this a coincidence that I'm overinterpreting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The words have different roots, and there doesn't appear to be a direct connection.

Per [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tholian) (referencing *These Are the Voyages: TOS Season Three*)

> T*he name came from an expedition that an acquaintance of mine had actually been on – a geologist named Jack Green, who had gone to the Aegean islands and, after some digging, had discovered a collapsed [Tholos tomb](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beehive_tomb), complete with its contents. So Tholos became Tholian."* ~ <sub><sup>Chet Richards</sup></sub>